# Resampling while drawing rasterfiles in QGIS 3?

Tags: qgis, interpolation, resampling, drawing

I can not find a solution to resample my rasterfiles in QGIS 3. With Arcmap usually I use "resample while drawing" with the method cubic or bilinear interpolation for continuous data to smooth my drawing (like the second image). The cell size is quite big so it makes no sense for my task (heatmap) to visualize the rastercells themselves.

Original rasterdata:

[image: original rasterdata]

Resampled while drawing:

[image: resampled while drawing]